# Usage of a constant pointer to an integer in a controlled environment

Tags: c, pointers, struct, constants

```
unsigned int H_SMPTR_LEN = 0;
#ifndef _RSZLEN
#define _RSZLEN(nvalue) H_SMPTR_LEN = nvalue;
#endif

//Smart pointer structure with built-in size
typedef struct SMPTR
{
     void *MBLOC;
     const unsigned int *length;
     unsigned int bloc_size;
} SMPTR;
#ifndef _SMPTR
#define _SMPTR(SMPTR, var_sz, v_num) SMPTR.MBLOC = malloc(var_sz * v_num); SMPTR.bloc_size = v_num * var_sz; _RSZLEN(v_num); SMPTR.length = &H_SMPTR_LEN; 
#endif
```

I wrote this code to experiment with const * to an integer. When I run and implement the code above like so:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "cdebug.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    SMPTR s;
    _SMPTR(s, sizeof(char), 50);

    fprintf(stdout, "%i\n", s.bloc_size);
    fprintf(stdout, "%i\n", s.length);
    fprintf(stdout, "%i\n", H_SMPTR_LEN);
    fprintf(stdout, "%s", "Done!\n");

    return 0;
}
```

The second output statement is a screwy output result. In theory the second output result should match the third, because the SMPTR.length member points to H_SMPTR_LEN.

The first bit of code is part of my header called "cdebug.h", which is included in main(). I am wondering if I am using const pointers correctly here. The idea here is to create a structure whose members can only be modified in a controlled environment, i.e. a method I write.

Comment: USe `gcc -C -E` to get the preprocessed form of your code.

Comment: i need help with const pointers

Comment: When you compile, what does the warning say? If there is no warning try compiling with `-Wall` if gcc or `-W4` if Microsoft. If that still doesn't generate a warning, get a better compiler.

Comment: $ gcc sprintftest.c -Wall -o sprintftest
sprintftest.c: In function ‘main’:
sprintftest.c:11:2: warning: format ‘%i’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘const unsigned int *’ [-Wformat=]
  fprintf(stdout, "%i\n", s.length);
  ^
sprintftest.c:11:2: warning: format ‘%i’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘const unsigned int *’ [-Wformat=]

Comment: Ok, let me simplify that for you: `expects type 'int', but has type 'int*'`.  What does that tell you?

Comment: change to `fprintf(stdout, "%i\n", *s.length);` : `length` is pointer.

Comment: Please add the gcc command and warning message *to the question*.

Comment: NOTE: identifiers with a leading underscore are reserved for the language and/or the implementation. In other words: dont use `_SMPTR()` or `_RSZLEN` as macro names.